# Hilbert space "basis weighting operator." Is it well-defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(e_n) = (e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$.
Let $(a_n)$ be an **arbitrary** sequence of complex numbers.
In multiple textbooks, I see an operator $T:H \to H$ defined by
$$
Te_n = a_n e_n
$$

Thus
$$
Tx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \langle x,e_n \rangle e_n
$$

Is this operator well-defined?

I can see that if $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then the operator is bounded:
$$
\| Tx \|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 |\langle x,e_n \rangle|^2 \leq \sup_n |a_n|^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_n \rangle|^2 = \|x\|^2
$$

But if $(a_n)$ is an **arbitrary** sequence of complex numbers, I don't see why $\| Tx \|$ should be finite, i.e., I don't see why the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \langle x,e_n \rangle e_n$ should converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not well-defined. Take $x=\sum \frac 1n e_n$ which is a convergent series. Then the series defining $Tx$ converges iff $\sum \frac  1n a_ne_n$ converges iff $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}|a_n|^{2} <\infty$. Take $a_n =n$ to see that this can fail.

Answer (score 0):

It is implicitly assumed that $T$ is defined as an *unbounded* operator. This means that you also need to specify its domain. Typically in this case the domain is assumed to be
$$
\{ x\in H \ :\ \sum |a_n|^2 \lvert \langle x, e_n\rangle \rvert^2 <\infty\}.$$
Except trivial cases (such as $H$ being finite dimensional), this coincides with $H$ if and only if $a_n$ is bounded, in which case $T$ is a bounded operator.